# Error install forem gem on rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

*Was anyone able to install this gem with 4.2.1?*
This is what I got after running bundle install:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People at forem say they're waiting for the next rails update `4.2.2` to fix the capability issue. It seems to work on 4.1.x in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

forem depends on rails <= 4.2. You cannot use this gem with rails 4.2.1. The forem's description on rubygems is `The best Rails 3 forum engine in the world.`

Comment: Like I said: `rails <= 4.2`. `4.1.x <= 4.2` :) The description was just a comment.